# First and Second-Best

Tags: general-equilibrium, environmental-economics

Why are environmental instruments like Pigovian-taxes or the Coase-Theorem viewed as first-best solutions, while taxes or tradable permits are viewed as second best? How do they differ, and what makes a first-best solution a first-best solution?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "how do they differ"? Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's not. I came across an article last morning. It was quite an interesting read but I left with open questions.  Well it's hard to describe. I just want to know why a Pigovian tax can lead to a first best solution and tradeable permits cannot? And I don't quite get the difference between a first-best solution and a second best.

Comment: Could you please edit a link to the article into your question?

Comment: Tradable permits (and taxes) can reach a first-best solution too, provided you get the amount of permits (or the tax rate) right and there are no other complications

Comment: FYI: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/what-is-the-definition-of-first-best-second-best-etc-in-contract-theory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the definition of "First Best", "Second Best", etc. in contract theory?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/what-is-the-definition-of-first-best-second-best-etc-in-contract-theory)